# Sort subdomains based on domains

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have list of domains and sub-domains like

```
abc.com
def.com
ijk.com
pages.abc.com
help.abc.com
contactus.def.com
help.def.com
```

My Requirement is to sort this list by domains, such that the final output is

```
abc.com
pages.abc.com
help.abc.com
def.com
contactus.def.com
ijk.com
```

How can i achieve this in C#? Im new to C# programming. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you made an error sorting the example but here's a solution:

```
class DomainComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if(x==y) return 0;
        string[] _x = x.Split('.');
        string[] _y = y.Split('.');
        return Compare(_x, _y, 0);
    }

    private int Compare(string[] x, string[] y, int depth)
    {
        if (x.Length - depth - 1 >= 0 && y.Length - depth -1 < 0)
        {
            return +1;
        }

        if (y.Length - depth - 1 >= 0 && x.Length - depth -1 < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (x[x.Length-depth-1].CompareTo(y[y.Length - depth-1]) == 0)
        {
            return Compare(x, y, depth + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return x[x.Length-depth-1].CompareTo(y[y.Length - depth-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
string[] domains = new[] { "abc.com", "def.com", "ijk.com", "pages.abc.com", "help.abc.com", "contactus.def.com", "help.def.com" };

Array.Sort(domains, new DomainComparer());
foreach (var item in domains)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);    
}
```

Output:

```
abc.com
help.abc.com
pages.abc.com
def.com
contactus.def.com
help.def.com
ijk.com
```

Or if you dont have an array but a

```
List<string>
```

or an

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

you can do it with Linq:

```
IEnumerable<string> sorted = domains.OrderBy(x => x, new DomainComparer());
```

Comment: Added special case if you dont have distinct domains

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to sort by second level domain & TLD then you can do something like this.

```
var uriList = new string[] {"abc.com", "def.com", "ijk.com", "pages.abc.com", 
     "help.abc.com", "contactus.def.com", "help.def.com"};
var query = from uri in uriList.Select(item => 
    new { Uri = item, UriParts = item.Split('.') }) 
    orderby uri.UriParts[uri.UriParts.Length-2] + uri.UriParts[uri.UriParts.Length-1],
    string.Join(".", uri.UriParts) select uri.Uri;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ,", query));
```

The output will be slightly different from what you are expecting, like this.

abc.com, help.abc.com, pages.abc.com, contactus.def.com, def.com, help.def.com, ijk.com

Answer (score 0):

it could be done like this:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("abc.com");
        list.Add("def.com");
        list.Add("ijk.com");
        list.Add("pages.abc.com");
        list.Add("help.abc.com");
        list.Add("contactus.def.com");
        list.Add("help.def.com");
        List<string> listRoot = new List<string>();
        List<string> listSub = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            string[] split = item.Split(new char[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (split.Length == 2)
            {
                listRoot.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                listSub.Add(item);
            }
        }
        listRoot.Sort();
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        foreach (string root in listRoot)
        {
            List<string> listSubIntern = new List<string>();
            foreach (string item in listSub)
            {
                if (item.EndsWith(root, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    listSubIntern.Add(item);
                }
            }
            listSubIntern.Sort();
            dictionary.Add(root, listSubIntern);
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> keyValuePair in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Key);
            foreach (string s in keyValuePair.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", s);
            }
        }
```

and the output:

```
abc.com
    help.abc.com
    pages.abc.com
def.com
    contactus.def.com
    help.def.com
ijk.com
```